# LaTeX a jumbled mess when flagging as a duplicated

Tags: support, bug, mathjax, exact-duplicates

Is it normal for the LaTeX to be a jumbled mess when flagging as a duplicate?

[image]

In case it isn't all systems, I am on a Linux system with Firefox 34.0.

Comment: It is normal. Fortunately, when you chose the duplicate, that is displayed correctly.

Comment: @DanielFischer then it is a bug that needs to be fixed.

Comment: It would indeed be nice to get it fixed.

Comment: I _think_ this is a duplicate, but I have not found one. If somebody with better searching skills wants to try, be welcome.

Comment: @DanielFischer I couldn't find a post when I posted this as well.

Comment: It was also mentioned [in a comment](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/17530/mathjax-2-5-alpha?cb=1#comment67446_17530) on the MathJax 2.5 alpha thread.

Comment: @DanielFischer is this new to 2.5 or was it occurring prior?

Comment: I think it's older. But I'm not 100% sure.